# :nth-child within Bootstrap rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

Currently, I have a page that loads a PHP array and creates rows, within Bootstrap. The PHP is generating a random number for the column count (col-sm-4, col-sm-3, etc. is created randomly, until it adds up to 12).

Example of one row within the Bootstrap container:

```
    <div class="row equal project-row">
        <article class="col-sm-4 project">
            <header class="project-title">title</header>
            <p class="project-desc">text</p>
        </article>
        <article class="col-sm-3 project">
            <header class="project-title">title</header>
            <p class="project-desc">text</p>
        </article>
        <article class="col-sm-4 project">
            <header class="project-title">title</header>
            <p class="project-desc">text</p>
        </article>
        <article class="col-sm-1 project">
            <header class="project-title">title</header>
            <p class="project-desc">text</p>
        </article>
    </div>
```

I then have some CSS which is setting the background color of each `<article>`, iterating through 5 different choices. It is based on the **project** class.

CSS:

```
.project:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background: rgba(32,78,127,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+2) {
    background: rgba(6,133,135,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+3) {
    background: rgba(79,185,159,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+4) {
    background: rgba(109,242,87,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+5) {
    background: rgba(214,77,53,1);
}
```

However, the iterated colors only change within each row; for example, in the example row in the above code, it would show the first four colors (5n+1, 5n+2, 5n+3, and 5n+4), but then if there were a SECOND row, it would start back at 5n+1 INSTEAD of going to 5n+5.

I realize this is caused by the rows - before adding those in, this worked fine. But I'm a bit lost on the best method to use, within my current framework, so that the project classes are iterated through completely.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g9RXW/), with two rows to show that it does not iterate through all 5 color options (5th is a reddish color).

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a server language to output the rows, you could use a MOD function then have if statements to add a class for row color depending on the MOD output.

Another option is to use jquery to do the same type thing. Iterate through each row, at index 1 addClass('bgcolor-blue'), if 2 addClass('bgcolor-ltblue').....and so on.

This would be a clear example on the best approach.

```
<style>
.project:nth-child(5n+1) {
    background: rgba(32,78,127,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+2) {
    background: rgba(6,133,135,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+3) {
    background: rgba(79,185,159,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+4) {
    background: rgba(109,242,87,1);
}
.project:nth-child(5n+5) {
    background: rgba(214,77,53,1);
}

</style>


<div class='row equal project-row'>
    <article class="col-sm-4 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-sm-4 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-sm-1 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
</div>

<div class='row equal project-row'>
    <article class="col-sm-4 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-sm-3 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-sm-4 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-sm-1 project">
        <header class="project-title">title</header>
        <p class="project-desc">text</p>
    </article>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('article').unwrap();  
    $('article').wrapAll('<div class="row equal project-row">')      

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/judsonmusic/5uqZM/5/

I hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Judson! I was thinking I may have touse jQuery - any way at all to do it solely with the nth-child, etc. selectors in CSS?

Comment: Not really, because you are breaking the structure up physically by creating rows for every 4 .project class article tags. My suggestion would be to redo your markup either static, or write a jquery plugin that would wrap the markup in the project row tag every 5th one that is generated. I will create a jsFiddle to show you.....

Comment: I edited my original answer. Just bear in mind, from an architectural standpoint, you need to be aware of what you are visually trying to produce, are you trying to visual represent groups of 5? a total group? etc. Your markup should go hand in hand with this. If your markup has to remain the way you have it, my solution works just fine. You can also change it to use a .each() to iterate through them, then every 5th one, end and start a new project-row div, etc. This is all I have. :)

Comment: Huge help; needed an outside look at this and you're clearly the right person to have seen it! Thanks so much. Cheers! -z

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of assistance!